# enumerate() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get this error: TypeError: enumerate() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.

I have tried len(menu) but i get an error.

```py
import socket
import urllib.request
import os
import curses
import time
import subprocess
from threading import *
from queue import Queue

menu = ['Play','Score','Help','Exit']
for idx, row in enumerate(menu):
    x  = w//2 - len(row)//2
    y = h//2 - len(menu)//2 + idx
    ax = w//3
    i += 1
    if idx == select_row:
       stdscr.attron(curses.color_pair(2))
       stdscr.addstr(y,ax, '->')
       stdscr.attroff(curses.color_pair(2))

       stdscr.attron(curses.color_pair(1))
       stdscr.addstr(y,x,row)
       stdscr.attroff(curses.color_pair(1))
    else:
       stdscr.addstr(y,x,row)

       stdscr.refresh()
```

Comment: Is this all of your code? Do you have a variable/function somewhere else that is named `enumerate`?

Comment: no there are no variables/function named enumerate.

Comment: Try printing `enumerate` and `type(enumerate)`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, although, you haven't even tried to provide a [mcve]

Comment: the output in python3 shell is:  <class 'type'>

Comment: do you want more code

Comment: No, we want a [mcve]

Comment: @programmer did you import all your files in the shell when you ran that?

Comment: @kylie.a I did import all files

Comment: What is the output of `help(enumerate)`

Comment: output is: class enumerate(object)
 |  enumerate(iterable, start=0)
 |  
 |  Return an enumerate object.
 |  
 |    iterable
 |      an object supporting iteration
 |  
 |  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a count (from start, which
 |  defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument.
 |  
 |  enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:
 |      (0, seq[0]), (1, seq[1]), (2, seq[2]), ...
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __getattribute__(self, name, /)
 |      Return getattr(self, name).

Comment: It would appear at least in the context of your shell the symbol `enumerate` is pointing to the correct object. If you set a breakpoint before `enumerate` is called while the code is running is the output of `type/help` the same?

Comment: i can post all code if youd like

Comment: And *this* is why you ***don't use `import *`***.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`threading` has a [`threading.enumerate` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate) that returns a list of the Thread objects for all live threads. Your `import *` imports that, hiding the builtin.

Stop using `import *`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your code; you may be having a function with the same name. I ran the following code and it did not throw error

```
menu = [[4.5,3.5]]

w = 3.5
h=2.6

for idx, row in enumerate(menu):

        x  = w//2 - len(row)//2
        y = h//2 - len(menu)//2 + idx
        ax = w//3
        i += 1
```

Comment: But that's not the entire code, is it?

Comment: no there's much more